# nested set model sorting

Tags: sql, sqlite, hierarchy, nested-sets

yo,

on this page [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)
there is an awesome comparison of options for storing hierarchies. For me it looks like nested set is the best, but there it mentions "Requires a specific sort order". Can anybody explain what exactly does that imply? Will I be able to get a sorted list of ascendants/descendants fast only I sort them by id? Even if I have indexes on other columns that I'm trying to use for sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the nested set model, the tree structure is implied by the order in which the nodes are traversed.

If you want a sort order different from that for which the tree was created, you have to read the results first, and then sort them manually in a second step.
(After rows have been read from a table, indexes are no longer useful.)